# TBXML Parser with Special character getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am using TBXML Parser ver. 1.4, When I am Parsing this kind of following responce via TBXML parser, getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS...

```
<trainingOrganization xsi:type="xsd:string">~!@#$%^&*()_+?> <,./;'{}|<":;'></trainingOrganization>
```

Stuck with this issue.

As I observe that <> data is failed to parse by TBXML...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how about escaping? `\<` and `\>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best way to use CDATA, anything inside of CDATA treat as xml document so if you have special character like ';:,.''<>' then parser will ignore it. So I always prefer to use CDATA and advise you to should use it.

Comment: Its Works for me...Thanks Sachin...Good Work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's nothing TBXML parser specific.

Chars like `<>\"'` have to be masked (by a `\`), so it's maybe only the coding of your xml file or the settings for its parsing.

Otherwise the parser thinks it is :

```
<trainingOrganization xsi:type="xsd:string">
~!@#$%^&*()_+?
> *<-- closing the previous element* 
<,./;'{}|
  <":;'>
</trainingOrganization>
```

If you can't find any settings or coding to let do it automaticaly, try it by replacing the characters with a `\` in front of it before parsing.

An other possibility is to use xml correctly and not allow the structure to set `<>` between elements, which is an easiest way i think.